# Detect screen on/off in mobile javascript

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, signalr

I have a webpage using signalr and a countdown timer that is updated via the signalr.

On iPhone if the screen is turned off and/or times out and goes black, and the user turns it back on the countdown timer doesn't respond right away and takes awhile to start counting down again.

Can I detect the webpage coming back into view on iPhone and Android with javascript?

Comment: @Rami I don't see any onResume in the javascript documentation, is that implemented by the Android browsers?

Comment: That's good to know @Rami, but my question is concerning the web page and the javascript on the page. I'm not using Java, or a native app.

Comment: no need to remove them, it'll keep someone else from making the same comments